# Use mod_fcgid instead of mod_php

Tags: jelastic

I'd like to use mod_fcgid instead of mod_php at my Jelastic environment for reasons like better memory footprint and mod_spdy support.

Is there a way to configure Jelastic to do so? I can upload all needed modules by myself. But what about apache mpm-worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is using the Elastic VPS node type. Since you'll need to do some manual setup anyway, this will allow you to get everything just how you want - and of course still combined with other standard database or load balancing nodes etc.

Comment: Got it working, thank you! However, one problem persists: I added the VDS node to an already existing environment with apache, memcache and mysql. Now I can't connect to mysql as my VDS can't reach 192.168.x.x. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes. By default your VDS only has a public IP (not private network access) Ask your provider if they will enable the private network on your VDS. Otherwise you have to add a public IP to the MySQL node (not recommended for security reasons).